# Can ipmasq and ufw be used together?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, iptables, ufw

**If both ufw and ipmasq manipulate iptables, can I use ipmasq for a quick easy setup and then use ufw afterwards to add security or will the two just trample all over the iptables "stuff"?**

I'm playing with Ubuntu 11.04 and attempting to set up a firewall.  My system has two ethernet adapters, eth1 on the external side and eth2 on the internal side.  I attempted to follow the instructions here http://www.routermods.com/2010/02/09/ubuntu-firewall-ufw-uncomplicated-firewall-basics/ about IP Masquerading, but I believe my comprehension breaks down here:

```
# Forward traffic from eth1 through eth0.
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I believe I'm supposed to be forwarding from eth2 through eth1.  I don't know if I should change the IP address.  My assumption is that is the internal subnet "range"; however, no internal systems are receiving IP addresses.  I suspect I need to run a DHCP server on the firewall to make this happen.  After some more browsing, I found a few bloggers mentioning the ease of use of ipmasq.

So, all of that led to the question.